# Grab multiple select values and display results in a specific format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I have a select multiple dropdown where user can select multiple values.  I'm trying to make a script that grabs those values, then displays the output in the following format:

```
Test1, Test2, Test3 and Test4
```

However if only two values are selected to have it in this format

```
Test1 and Test2
```

And if it's just a single value:

```
Test1
```

I've gotten close to how I want it to look but I can only get a space between either the first, or the last not all instances.

Here is what I have for my HTML:

```
<select multiple id="FixAgent" onChange="myFixAgentList1();myFixAgentList2();myFixAgentList3();">
  <option value="Test1">Test1</option>
  <option value="Test2">Test2</option>
  <option value="Test3">Test3</option>
  <option value="Test4">Test4</option>
</select>

<textarea id="FixAgentListArray1" rows="1" cols="50" style="visibility: hidden;"></textarea>
<textarea id="FixAgentListArray2" rows="1" cols="50" style="visibility: hidden;"></textarea>
<textarea id="FixAgentListArray3" rows="1" cols="50"></textarea>
```

The last `textarea` is not hidden as the other two are just used to store different variables to be used for the next function.

Here are my scripts:

```
function getFixedAgentValues(select) {
  var result = [];
  var options = select && select.options;
  var opt;

  for (var i = 0, iLen = options.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    opt = options[i];
    if (opt.selected) {
      return result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function myFixAgentList1() {
  var a = document.getElementById("FixAgent");
  document.getElementById("FixAgentListArray1").innerHTML = getFixedAgentValues(a);

  function myFixAgentList2() {
    var a = document.getElementById("FixAgentListArray1").value;

    if (a.includes(",")) {
      var b = a.lastIndexOf(",");
      var c = a.substring(0, b) + " and " + a.substring(b + 1);
      document.getElementById("FixAgentListArray2").innerHTML = c;
    } 
    else {
      document.getElementById("FixAgentListArray2").innerHTML = a;
    }
  }

  function myFixAgentList3() {
    var a = document.getElementById("FixAgentListArray2").value;

    if (a.includes(",")) {
      var b = a.lastIndexOf(",");
      var c = a.substring(0, b) + " , " + a.substring(b + 1);
      document.getElementById("FixAgentListArray3").innerHTML = c;
    } 
    else {
      document.getElementById("FixAgentListArray3").innerHTML = a;
    }
  }
```

I am not sure who to get it to replace every value of "," with ", " for three or more values selected, have "and" used to separate the last two or if only two values selected.

If there is a way to do this without so many hidden fields and just have it pull and display the values in one shot using JavaScript in a short script would be good too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple **switch()** block would do you good here.
Based on the number of selected options you can construct a string ready to be displayed.

```
function getFixedAgentValues(select) {
  var retString = "";
  var result = [];
  var options = select && select.options;
  var opt;

  for (var i = 0, iLen = options.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    opt = options[i];
    if (opt.selected) {
      result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
    }
  }
  switch (result.length) {
    case 1:
      retString = result[0];
      break;
    case 2:
      retString = result[0] + " and " +
        result[1];
      break;
    case 3:
      retString = result[0] + ", " +
        result[1] + " and " + result[2];
      break;
    case 4:
      retString = result[0] + ", " +
        result[1] + ", " + result[2] + " and " + result[3];
      break;
  }
  return retString;
}


function myFixAgentList1() {
  var a = document.getElementById("FixAgent");
document.getElementById("FixAgentListArray1").innerHTML=getFixedAgentValues(a);
}
```

and the slightly modified html

```
<select multiple id="FixAgent" onChange="myFixAgentList1();">
```

Comment: I tried your switch block but it doesn't post the results into the textarea field?  How would it post into the text area?

Comment: I modified your **myFixAgentList1()** function in my answer above to output the text to **FixAgentListArray1**. Just remember it's visibility is hidden!

Comment: Awesome.  This works perfectly and leave it open for added values.  Thank you so much :-)

Comment: var stringResult = "";
if(result.length > 1){
    var tempArray = result.slice(0,result.length - 1);
    stringResult = tempArray.join(", ") + " and " + result[result.length - 1];
} else {
 stringResult = result;
}


 ---------------- instead of switch this if else block will work for any length of string

Comment: @satwik that gives me an undefined error if I replace the switch block with that script.

Comment: function getFixedAgentValues(select) {
  var retString = "";
  var result = [];
  var options = select && select.options;
  var opt;

  for (var i = 0, iLen = options.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    opt = options[i];
    if (opt.selected) {
      result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
    }
  }

  if(result.length > 1){ 
   var tempArray = result.slice(0,result.length - 1); 
   return tempArray.join(", ") + " and " + result[result.length - 1]; 
  }
  return result; 

}      ------    replace getFixedAgentValues function with this.   @Michael